# Is there a way to dynamically change the class of a single header in slick-grid 1.4.3?

Tags: header, slickgrid

I noticed that the latest version of slick-grid has a 'headerCssClass' attribute on the column, which would work great, except I am restricted to using slick-grid version 1.4.3.

I am extending slick-grid so as to add multiple column sort functionality and will need to set the class of each sort header accordingly. So, to re-iterate the question, does anyone know of a way to dynamically change the class of any given header in slick-grid 1.4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really love this solution, as it is not preferred to use JQuery to modify the slick-grid, but here goes:

```
var headers = $('.slick-header-columns').get(0).children;
```

remove any non-default class information from all the headers(i.e., `$(headers).removeClass('slick-header-column-sorted')`)

iterate through the columns of the slick-grid and use JQuery to add a class at the wanted column index

```
var header = headers[wantedColIdx];
$(header).addClass('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with jQuery.

Add a blank css class with some name.

Then you can call addClass and removeClass to change the class dynamically.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

i.e.

```
jQuery('.my-class').addClass('new-header-class');
```

Comment: Ya, I had thought about doing that, but I think the only way I could access the correct header cell to change it's class would be to define an onClick() function for the slick-grid and override what it is currently doing if the cell happens to be a header cell -- this would probably work, except it seems to suggest potential for unknown issues.

Comment: Additionally, it appears that an 'onClick' event is not fired if the cell does not represent an actual item (so would not work for header cells).

Comment: You can call that from anywhere, it does not require onclick, as long as you have 'my-class' or whatever added to what you care about.